# Game of Keno: What is the percent chance that a player selects exactly 3 winning numbers?

Tags: probability

In the game of Keno, a player starts by selecting 20 numbers from the numbers 1 to 80. After the player makes his selections, 20 winning numbers are randomly selected from numbers 1 to 80. A win occurs if the player has correctly selected 3,4, or 5 of the 20 winning numbers.
May anyone give me a hint to solve this problem, please? Thanks!

Comment: 1) Count how many combinations of 20 numbers can be drawn from a set of 80 numbers. 2) You have 20 winning numbers and 60 losing numbers. Count how many combinations can be formed with $n$ winning numbers and $20-n$ losing numbers. 3) Divide what you get at step 2 by what you got at step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of ways to select 20 out of 80 is $\binom{80}{20}$. The player needs to select 3,4, or 5 of these AND the rest from the remaining 60 numbers: $\binom{20}{3} \times \binom{60}{17} + \binom{20}{4} \times \binom{60}{16} +\binom{20}{5} \times \binom{60}{15}$. Can you sort out the rest?

Comment: Thanks all! The percent chance: C(20,3) . C(60,17) / C(80,20) = 12.48%